# How to receive data of an HTTPS website in a string PHP?

Tags: php, https

Is there a function to which you give the URL of a website and it returns back the source in a string?

Comment: since I am pretty sure to have provided the correct answer, could you please accept my answer **or** edit your question to point out why my answer is not solving your problem.

Comment: Your answer solved the question yes, but not the exact answer which I was looking for. I was parsing an XML file and your method brought back only the contents in the XML file without the tags or anything. However, I was able to do that through XML reader. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

- [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) — Reads entire file into a string. A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.

Example:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.example.com');
```

Otherwise [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [HTTP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) will do.

If you want to parse the contents on the page, [you will likely want use a DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) instead.